How to call derived type methods from vector of base type stored in a different class?
say I have some class foo that has a vector of pointers to another class Bar and a LogBarVec() method that logs each Bar's internal type:
class Foo {
     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> m_BarVec;

     void LogBarVec() const {
           for(auto& b : m_BarVec) {
              b->Log();
           }

     }
}

Bar is a base type with a pure virtual Log method :
class Bar {
public:
     Bar(){};
     virtual void Log() const = 0;
}

and BarDerived is a class derived from Bar :
class BarDerived : public Bar {
     int number  = 0;
public:
     BarDerived(float num) : Bar(), number(num){};

     void Log() const override {
         std::cout << "BarDerived number: " << number << std::endl;  
     }
}


My question is, what is the correct way to access the Bars' internal type's Log method from Foo? In other words?
EDIT:
For some context, I have a container of a bunch of Foos in main in which each BarDerived has a different number, for example,
Foo[0] BarDerived[0] number = 4, BarDerived[1] number = 3
Foo[1] BarDerived number = 6;
int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++) {
       foo->LogBarVec();
    }

   return 0;

}


My desired output is so :
Foo[0] -> BarDerived number: 4, BarDerived number: 3
Foo[1] -> BarDerived number: 6
etc...

I get an error stating "Log is not a member of std::unique_ptr<Bar, std::default_delete>"

What is the current output and expected output. Do you get any error, if yes post the complete error.

Yes, you just call Log on the Bar object. Your compiler should have complained about your classes needing virtual destructors, though. Also, your derived Log needs to be virtual too (again, no idea why your compiler didn't complain about the override not overriding it properly...).

The question is unclear. The posted piece of code doesn't seem to have any problem (except Bar needs a virtual dtor). Is sonmething not working?

Add a public const auto& getBars() const noexcept { return m_BarVec; } to your baseclass amd then you can use that in your log method for (const auto& bar : getBars()) : std::cout << bar << "\n"; (after providing a std::ostream operator<< overload for Bar ofcourse)

The provided code seems correct to me, how are you creating the objects? Please post a [mcve] .

First of all, since Bar is BarDerived's base class, in order to avoid slicing, you should declare a vector of std::unique_ptr<Bar*> (not just Bar).
Using pointer to Bar, you'll be able to insert any Bar's derived class.
Even if you have declared as Base class, since it is a pointer to its derived one, the overrided method will be called.
Edit:
class Bar{
  public:
    Bar(){}
    virtual void log() const = 0;
};

class BarDerived : public Bar{
  public:
    BarDerived() : Bar(){}
    void log() const override{
        std::cout<<"Derived";
    }
};

class Foo{

  public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> vec;

    void LogBarVec(){
        for(auto &b : vec){
            Bar* b1 = b.get();
            b1->log();
        }
    }
};

int main(){

Foo f;
BarDerived b;
f.vec.push_back( std::make_unique<Bar>(b) );
}

If you try to compile these lines, you will get stuck on this error:

error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Bar’

Therefore you have to declare std::unique_ptr<Bar*> otherwise you should define with an empty body the base method. Be aware that, declaring Bar*, the get() method of the smart ptr will return a pointer to pointer...

I don't quite get your idea about making a std::unique_ptr<Bar*> -- I don't think I've ever had to do that for anything, and it kind of defeats the purpose of std::unique_ptr, since destructing it will deallocate the pointer, but not the object it points to...

About that, using pointer, it will only deallocate pointer just like you said; therefore you should implement a mechanism which free object once the pointer is released. About why you should use Bar*, it is due to the pure virtual method Log() and even to slicing. I've compiled your code right now again and I confirm these bugs (slicing and abstract method error). Have you figured 'em out by youself?
